# Create a new role dynamically using Elasticsearch Java Client

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-shield

I have an elasticsearch(2.4.4) server and I'm using elasticsearch java client to manage indicies. I've added authentication with elasticsearch shield plugin(2.2.0) and it works properly. Now, i want to create new roles dynamically but it seems that not possible to do this using client.

Is it the only way making API requests to manage roles dynamically or am i missing something?

Comment: so, you want java api to do some stuff with shield, which is a plugin? i do think it's possible, since java api is just doing basic which is always inside Elastic